# Getting error :- unfortunately app has stopped in android

Tags: java, android, xml, ant, logcat

I have been searching for this for hours but all in vain.I am developing a tutorial app named Yamba from the book *learning android* .It is an app to update status on twitter.It uses [jtwitter.jar](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjuiLeRrqbHAhVUBY4KHTjaBwc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.winterwell.com%2Fsoftware%2Fjtwitter.php&ei=37XMVa6dL9SKuAS4tJ84&usg=AFQjCNEXMq-Iom5KLQdmZCn4gBOFFCal3g&sig2=JLwsSnxc1LyzwBW07oYP9w&bvm=bv.99804247,d.c2E) library. Things which I am using :

> 1. linux(ubuntu)
> 2. ant debug ( to build my project)
> 3. my android phone for testing the app.

The project builds successfully and installs the app on my phone but when I run the app, I get the error "*unfortunately, Yamba has stopped*".I have the following files:

AndroidManifest.xml file as--

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.Yamba"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name=".Yamba"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

my Yamba.java file as --

```
package com.example.Yamba;

import winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
public class Yamba extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private static final String TAG = "Yamba";
    EditText editText;
    Button updateButton;
    Twitter twitter;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.status);

            //find views
            editText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            updateButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);

            updateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            twitter = new Twitter("student","password");
            twitter.setAPIRootUrl("http://yamba.marakana.com/api");
        }
    public void onClick(View view){
        twitter.setStatus(editText.getText().toString());
        Log.d(TAG,"onClicked");
    }
}
```

my layout.xml as ----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
  <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/titleStatus"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    />
  <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/hintText"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal">
  </EditText>
  <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/buttonUpdate"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonUpdate">
  </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

my logcat is as follows ---

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
E/ObjectHelper( 6376): Can't find method:setCompatibilityInfo
E/Trace   ( 6342): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
E/jdwp    ( 6342): jdwp::setsockopt(SO_SNDTIMEO)
E/jdwp    ( 6342): jdwp::setsockopt(SO_RCVTIMEO)
E/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(  508): Object tried to add another callback
E/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(  508): java.lang.Exception: Called by
E/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(  508):         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardUpdateMonitor.registerCallback(KeyguardUpdateMonitor.java:1107)
E/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(  508):         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardSelectorView.onResume(KeyguardSelectorView.java:331)
E/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(  508):         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardHostView.onScreenTurnedOn(KeyguardHostView.java:1118)
E/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(  508):         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardViewManager.onScreenTurnedOn(KeyguardViewManager.java:404)
E/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(  508):         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardViewMediator.handleNotifyScreenOn(KeyguardViewMediator.java:1775)
E/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(  508):         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardViewMediator.access$2300(KeyguardViewMediator.java:106)
E/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(  508):         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.keyguard.KeyguardViewMediator$4.handleMessage(KeyguardViewMediator.java:1413)
E/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(  508):         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(  508):         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
E/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(  508):         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
E/AudioMTKHardware(  137): setParameters() still have param.size() = 1, remain param = "screen_state=on"
E/CellLocation(  784): create GsmCellLocation
E/CellLocation(  784): create GsmCellLocation
E/AndroidRuntime( 6411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AppErrorDialog(  508): Failed to get ILowStorageHandle instance
```

Clueless about what to do now.
Any help in this regard would be deeply appreciated.

**EDIT**-- I have posted my new logcat after removing the typo.

Comment: You have a typo in the permission name: `persmission`

Comment: in the right place ? I am sorry ? what do you mean by right place ? I have added it in the androidmanifest file that is what i have been reading on several posts

Comment: As @SergeyGlotov also just noticed - it is in the right place, it is just misspelt.

Comment: What does your logcat show now? If you have corrected the typing mistake,  this error is not possible. Try cleaning and rebuilding your project again.

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)`

Comment: It's strange, I don't see any critical error or stacktrace in the logcat.

Answer (score 3):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.persmission.INTERNET"/>
```

Wrongly named permission... It should be:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: The typo is removed but the problem still persists

Comment: The problem of internet permissions is solved though? Meaning that you don't have one error, you have two errors. Your logcat does not show any crash information for your App (that I can tell). Please run your App again and try to get a crash stacktrace relevant to your App.

Answer (score 1):

there is a typo error in android.**persmission**.INTERNET

Comment: The typo was just a result of the hangover I got by searching for hours its not originally placed in the xml file. The problem still persists

Comment: Make a try by placing the permission tag above the application element. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filestruct

Comment: Sorry, tried above also , but the problem still persists.

Comment: Can you please uninstall your app and install it again? also add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> with this  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html